# Azure blobs Java sdk can not return the list of versionIDs of an object

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

I am trying to get the list of versionIDs of an Azure blob via the Java SDK version 12.10.2 but it only returns the HTTP error 400 with the following error message

```
com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: Status code 400, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code><Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
RequestId:bd7e9a20-401e-003e-6d7b-37d0dd000000
Time:2021-04-22T13:29:12.0965760Z</Message><QueryParameterName>include</QueryParameterName><QueryParameterValue>versions</QueryParameterValue><Reason>Invalid query parameter value.</Reason></Error>"
```

And, this is my Java code:

```
public static BlobContainerAsyncClient getAzureAsyncClient(String accountName, String accountKey, String endpoint) {
        String connectionString = getConnectionString(accountName, accountKey, endpoint);
        BlobContainerAsyncClient blobServiceClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
          .connectionString(connectionString)
          .serviceVersion(version)
                  .buildAsyncClient();
    RWLog.MAIN.info("Azure Storage Async Service Client created for " + accountName);    
        return blobServiceClient;
}

BlobContainerAsyncClient containerClient = AzureConnection.getAzureAsyncClient(folder.getBucket(), folder.getSecretKey(), folder.getEndpoint());
    ListBlobsOptions ops = new ListBlobsOptions();
    ops.getDetails().setRetrieveVersions(true);
    ops.setPrefix(blobKey);
    PagedFlux<BlobItem> list =
        containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy("/", ops);
```

It looks like the HTTP request constructed by the Java SDK is not recognizable by the Azure blobs server. The server side is not able to process the versions-included query from the Java client.
Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of Java SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using the 12.10.2 of azure-storage-blob

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this using 12.10.2 of `azure-storage-blob` to get all versions of a blob:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

                String connString = "";
                String containerName = "";
                String blobName = "";

                BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connString).buildClient();

                BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = client.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
                ListBlobsOptions options = new ListBlobsOptions().setPrefix(blobName)
                                .setDetails(new BlobListDetails().setRetrieveVersions(true));

                Iterator<BlobItem> it = blobContainerClient.listBlobs(options, null).iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                        BlobItem item = it.next();
                        System.out.println(" versionID: " + item.getVersionId());
                }

        }
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

[image]